# Why does converting $\frac{1+\tan^{2}\theta}{1-\tan^{2}\theta}$ to $cos\;2\theta$ result in a wrong answer in trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry

One concept in Trigonometric Equations that is vehemently vouched for is to always try and eliminate $\tan\theta$ or avoid its use in such equations, as it can interfere in the domain of such questions (as $\tan\theta$ isn't defined at $\theta = \pi/2$). My doubt pertains to that in the following question.

Here we have the question:

> If $\tan(\cfrac{\pi}{4}+\theta)$ + $\tan(\cfrac{\pi}{4}-\theta)$ = 4, then $\theta$ = ? (general solution)

Solving it is fairly easy.

Let $\tan\theta = t$ (for convenience's sake)

$\tan\cfrac{\pi}{4} =1$

$$\frac{1+t}{1-t} +\frac{1-t}{1+t}=4$$

Taking LCM,

$$\cfrac{(1+t)^{2} + (1-t)^{2}}{1-t{^2}} = 4$$

$$\cfrac{2(1+t^{2})}{1-t^{2}} = 4$$

$$\cfrac{1+t^{2}}{1-t^{2}} = 2$$

Cross multiplying,

$$1 + t^{2} = 2 - 2t^{2}$$

$$3t^{2} = 1$$

$$t^{2} = \cfrac{1}{3}$$

$$\tan^{2}\theta = \tan^{2}\cfrac{\pi}{6}$$

$$\implies \theta = n\pi \pm \pi/6$$

Ergo we have solved the question.

However at the step

> $$\cfrac{1+t^{2}}{1-t^{2}} = 2$$, I recalled my professor's words and applied the formula for $\cos(2\theta) = \cfrac{1+\tan^{2}\theta}{1-\tan^{2}\theta}$.

$$\implies \cos(2\theta) = 2$$, which is not possible!

Here is my question. Why is this alternative method of applying $\cos(2\theta) = \cfrac{1+\tan^{2}\theta}{1-\tan^{2}\theta}$ wrong in this equation? I've applied the $\cos(2\theta)$ formula correctly, still it is giving the wrong answer. I'm sure it's something very silly and obvious to some users, but not to me, so some input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that identity for $\cos 2\theta$ is right - you've got the $+$ and the $-$ the wrong way around (so that identity is actually for $\sec 2\theta$).

Comment: Oh my, I just noticed. What a silly and obvious error. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: Don't worry about it! Your question was well written and has attracted several answers, so you shouldn't delete it (and in fact you can't). There are many questions on this site which are due to a mistake by the asker - that doesn't make them bad questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you misremembered what your professor said, or your professor was altogether wrong. Graphing the two, you can see they are clearly unequal:

[image]

Based on this graph, the correct identity would be the reciprocal:

$$\cos 2x = \frac{1 - \tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}$$

from which you would derive instead

$$\cos 2x = \frac 1 2$$

Comment: Yep, I mistakenly interchanged the numerator and denominator. What an ameteur thing to do!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1 + \tan^2 \theta}{1 - \tan^2 \theta} = \frac{\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta} = \frac{1}{\cos(2\theta)}$$

Maybe you need to memorize through deduction...Rote memorization just doesn't work, always